# Making tags visible when using a Tumblr theme that doesn't show them

Tags: tumblr, tumblr-themes

I have just created a [Tumblr](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tumblr) blog using the Fluid theme. After creating a new post, I added a few tags, but then I noticed that the tags do not show up along with the post.

I tried searching for an option to make the tags visible, but I could not find it. As it was pointed out, apparently not all themes display the tags.

How do I make the tags visible if using the Fluid theme? What changes do I have to make to its HTML?

Comment: The blog "missingfaktor" seems to have been moved off Tumblr.

Comment: @Peter: Yes, it's been moved to blogger.

Comment: The link to the now gone Tumblr isn't necessary, but at least we have the source code

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. Go to the [Customize](http://www.tumblr.com/customize) section after you  log in
2. Click on the **Theme** tab
3. Click **Use custom HTML**

This will bring up a edit box that contains the HTML and tumblr code used by the theme.

Put the code for the tags somewhere between the opening `{block:Posts}` and closing `{/block:Posts}` tags.

To start off easy, let's put the tags at the bottom of all your post types.

Where you see the following line:

```
{/block:Posts}
```

Insert the following starting chunk to look like this:

```
    {block:HasTags}
       {block:Tags}
          <a href="{TagURL}">{Tag}</a>
       {/block:Tags}
    {/block:HasTags}

{/block:Posts}
```

1. Click **Update preview** in the lower right corner of the edit box (or it will update itself)
2. Click **Save + Close** in the upper right of the dashboard.

Refresh your tumblr blog and you should now see the tags display.

You can read more of the specific tags markup needed on the [Tags section of "Creating a custom HTML theme"](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#tags)

Comment: I inserted the block of code you suggested and it worked, but with the theme I'm using, the tags ended up showing beneath the post box, so that the previous post sits on top of the tags, covering them up. Any suggestions?

Comment: @mir If tags are being blocked/overlapped by another post block, check the height mentioned in the CSS in case it's not allowing you enough height

Comment: [This post](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/18104/tumblr-tags-are-showing-below-the-posts-instead-of-inside-the-box) addresses the problem Miranda mentioned.

Comment: this isn't working for me? could it just be my particular theme or is there something i'm doing wrong?