# Tumblr tags are showing below the posts instead of inside the box

Tags: tumblr, tumblr-themes

I edited a [Tumblr layout to show tags on each post](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/14106/making-tags-visible-when-using-a-tumblr-theme-that-doesnt-show-them) but for some reason the tags are showing up below the post boxes, and right above the next post.

The code I have for the layout is as below (truncated):

```
{block:Posts}
    {block:Text}
       <li class="post text">
           <!-- HTML layout for Text posts -->
       </li>
    {/block:Text}

    {block:Photo}
       <li class="post photo">
           <!-- HTML layout for Photos -->
       </li>
    {/block:Photo}

    {block:Quote}
       <li class="post quote">
           <!-- HTML layout for quotes -->
       </li>
    {/block:Quote}

    {block:Link}
       <li class="post link">
           <!-- HTML layout for link posts -->
       </li>
    {/block:Link}

    <!-- etc. -->

    {block:HasTags}
        {block:Tags}
            <a href="{TagURL}">{Tag}</a>
        {/block:Tags}
    {/block:HasTags}
{/block:Posts}
```

I can't seem to figure out how/where to edit the theme so the tags show up within the post container and not floating outside and into the next post.

Answer (score 5):

It may be tedious, but it looks like you'll have to include the `HasTags` block in each of the section types.

Starting with the first you'll end up with this:

```
    {block:Text}
       <li class="post text">
           <!-- HTML layout for Text posts -->

        {block:HasTags}
            {block:Tags}
                <a href="{TagURL}">{Tag}</a>
            {/block:Tags}
        {/block:HasTags}

       </li>
    {/block:Text}
```

Where you currently have it appear just before `{/block:Posts}`, change it to be just before the closing `</li>` which appears to be what your post container styles are dressed in.

Don't forget to remove the block that appears just before the closing `{/block:Posts}` or you'll get the tags showing up twice.

Comment: That makes sense to me, however, it's still not working. I wonder if there's something else in the coding that's overriding it? Here's my edited version: http://pastebin.com/DsEdvxSY

Comment: Btw, just to add, I was helping a friend with the same problem on one of her tumblr layouts and that method DID work, but I had to place it within some div coding. Just to share what that looked like, I'm too tired to analyze the div coding atm. http://pastebin.com/8sdatk0V

Comment: Looks like in your template you'll have to put the code just before the tag that finishes the style block. @jam

Comment: ...why didn't I think of that? Yes! That worked! Thank you so much for your help and time. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

this worked with me but i'm not sure if it will work the same for you, paste:

```
{block:HasTags}
       {block:Tags}
          <a href="{TagURL}">{Tag}</a>
       {/block:Tags}
    {/block:HasTags}

{/block:Posts}
```

just after the opening of the notecount tag, so after `{block:PostNotes}` 
so it it looks a little something like:

```
{block:PostNotes}
{block:HasTags}
       {block:Tags}
          <a href="{TagURL}">{Tag}</a>
       {/block:Tags}
    {/block:HasTags}

{/block:Posts}<center>{block:RebloggedFrom}reblogged from <a href="{ReblogParentURL}">{ReblogParentName}</a><br>{/block:RebloggedFrom}
{block:ContentSource}posted by <a href="{SourceURL}">{SourceLink}</a></br>{/block:ContentSource}</center>
{PostNotes}
{/block:PostNotes}
```

this should ensure that tags are shown within the post box

Answer (score 1):

Put it right below the `{block:post}` instead of right above the `{/block:post}`

so...

```
{block:post}

{block:HasTags}
          {block:Tags}
              <a href="{TagURL}">{Tag}</a>
          {/block:Tags}
{/block:HasTags}

(all the different types of posts}
{/block:post}
```