# Showing tags in Tumblr in Munich theme

Tags: tumblr, tumblr-themes

I'm using the Munich theme for Tumblr, but it doesn't naturally show tags.  I've followed the instructions [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/14106/making-tags-visible-when-using-a-tumblr-theme-that-doesnt-show-them) and at the followup Tumblr FAQ for adding tags, but when the tags show up, they're far separated from the rest of the post and are in a chunky Times New Roman 12-point blue, not the style of the rest of the blog.  Has anyone had any luck adding tags to the Munich theme on Tumblr?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution:
At the bottom of the CSS, add:

```
#tags a {
    margin:20px 0 0 0;
    color:{color:Text};
    line-height:10px;
    color:{color:Links};
    text-decoration:none;
    font-variant:small-caps;
    font-family:Georgia;
    font-size:10px;
    position:relative;
    top:-75px;
}
```

And then place the HasTags code *immediately before* {/block:Posts}, so...

```
    {block:HasTags}
        <div id="tags">
            {block:Tags}
                <a href="{TagURL}">&nbsp;#{Tag}&nbsp;</a>
            {/block:Tags}
        </div>
    {/block:HasTags}
{/block:Posts}
```