# Making Tumblr tags visible only on permalink page

Tags: tumblr, tumblr-themes, tumblr-tags

I am currently using the [Quite Big](http://www.tumblr.com/theme/9601) Tumblr theme.  I have been able to add tags using [these instructions](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/14106/making-tags-visible-when-using-a-tumblr-theme-that-doesnt-show-them) among others, but would like to only have tags visible on permalink pages (for all post types).

Comment: You can indeed answer your own question, but most preferably not in the question itself. You can the question and mark the Q&A tick box.

Comment: Please add the solution as a proper answer to the question instead of putting it into the body of the question—you can answer your own question and accept the respective answer as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answered my own question:

Within the block for each post type (for example `{block:Quote}`), add at the end:

```
{block:PermalinkPage}
{block:HasTags}
   {block:Tags}
      <a href="{TagURL}">{Tag}</a>
   {/block:Tags}
{/block:HasTags}
{/block:PermalinkPage}

{/block:Quote}
```

**Do not** add before `{/block:Posts}`, as when adding tags to the main page.